# Negating multiple conditions in Bash

Tags: bash, negation

I realize this is a simple question, but I am finding a hard time getting an answer due to the finnicky syntax requirements in bash. I have the following script:

```
if ! [ [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ] ]; then
  echo "both arguments are set!"
fi
```

I get the following output when I run it without arguments:

> ```
> ./test: line 3: [: -z: binary operator expected 
> both arguments are set!
> ```

I am not expecting any output - neither argument is set. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to avoid negating with the `-n` test option.

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ quite the opposite. See the answer from Barmar

Comment: From boolean logic: `¬(A v B) => ¬A ^ ¬B`.

Comment: @Zloj Not really, `[[]]` is clearly a superior construct. Just because you can do it the way barmar has doesn't make it better...

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ but single brackets ensure portability, are more readable and less confusing. How can double brackets be better? Can you elaborate **why** exactly the `[[ ]]` construct is better?

Comment: @Zloj, they are portable, that's it. They are in no way more readable, they have less functionality and need everything to be quoted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `test` shell builtin `[` supports the arguments `-a` and `-o` which are logical AND and OR respectively.

```
#!/bin/sh 

if [ -n "$1" -a -n "$2" ]
then echo "both arguments are set!"
fi
```

Here I use `-n` to check that the strings are non-zero length instead of `-z` which shows that they *are* zero length and therefore had to be negated with a `!`.

" -n string     True if the length of string is nonzero."

"-z string     True if the length of string is zero."

If you are using `bash` it also supports a more powerful type of test `[[]]` which can use the boolean operators `||` and `&&`:

```
#!/bin/bash 

if [[ -n "$1" && -n "$2" ]]
then echo "both arguments are set!"
fi
```

In comments it was addressed that none of these samples show how to negate multiple tests in shell, here is an example which does:

```
#!/bin/sh 

if [ ! -z "$1" -a ! -z "$2" ]
then echo "both arguments are set!"
fi
```

Comment: In my original question I have the two tests in separate pairs of brackets. The purpose of this is that I might have more complex expressions with their own operators inside and it would be nice to be able to specify precedence with brackets or parentheses. Bash seems finicky about these as well. Can you explain how to group multiple subconditions together in the manner of the original question, so that a single logical operator can be applied to the compound expression?

Comment: In your penultimate example, I believe that `[[ -n "$1" || -n "$2" ]]` should be `[[ -n "$1" && -n "$2" ]]` (may as well remove the quotes too).

Comment: Updated to reflect your advice Dr. Fenech.

Answer (score 11):

Square brackets are not a grouping construct in `bash`. `[` is just an alias for the `test` command, the arguments are parsed normally. And `||` is a shell operator that separates commands.

If you want to group multiple commands, you can use the `()` subshell syntax.

```
if ! ([ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]);
```

or the `{ }` grouping syntax:

```
if ! { [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; };
```

Or you could use a single call to `test`, with its built-in `-o` operator:

```
if ! [ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" ]
```

Comment: I made a mistake with my first run - this doesn't actually work for me. The expression always returns true, and the statement that follows always executes. Perhaps I'm missing part of your intended script - could you provide a working example?

Comment: [`!` has higher precedence than `||`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/opprecedence.html), so you need to use a group (or better yet, rewrite the logic in a more sensible way).

Answer (score 6):

Remember (or learn!) that `[` is **not** part of shell syntax, it is a command.

If you want to group together multiple commands, then you should use `{ }`

```
if ! { [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; }
```

Note that the parser expects to see a line ending or semicolon before the closing `}`.

For the record, I'd avoid the negation and use `&&` here:

```
if [ -n "$1" ] && [ -n "$2" ]
```

...and since you specified [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you may as well take advantage of the enhanced test construct:

```
if [[ -n $1 && -n $2 ]]
```

Comment: You can put the and in the middle of the construct instead of making two instances.